# Running XSLT in Visual Studio 2012 not working anymore

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2012, dtd

I'm trying to run an xslt transform in Visual Studio; something I've done before without any issues in the past. I'm following the steps as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255828(v=vs.110).aspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
          test
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run the transform though, I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred while opening external DTD 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd': 
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

I tried to access the DTD there, and it downloaded fine. So I tried to point the namespace to a local file, and then I got this error:

```
Stylesheet must start either with an 'xsl:stylesheet' or an 'xsl:transform' element, 
or with a literal result element that has an 'xsl:version' attribute, where prefix 
'xsl' denotes the 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' namespace.
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What does your XML look like? I don't see any issues with the XSL. Though it also doesn't reference a DTD so if that is actually causing the error it would be in the XML somewhere.

Comment: Can you show how exactly you "tried to point the namespace to a local file"?

Comment: Ah, it seemed there was a problem with the XML file I was trying to transform...